# how fix rewrite rule conflict

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using following rewrite rule and its working fine :

```
1) RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/$ estates1.php?pageNum_Clusterb=$3&estname=$1&location=$2 [L]
```

but when add second code in my htaccess to use it , the second code not work :

```
2) RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ estates1zone.php?pageNum_Clusterb=$2&zone=$1 [L]
```

if first code disable , second code work , but together not working second code .
appear any conflict , Can you guide How can fix it ?

Comment: What URLs are you trying to match?

Comment: my database have location , type , zone , page , fist string get us location + type and page of result and secobd string get us zone , I wouldn't join 2 above string and want use them separately .

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict because the first rule matches the same pattern that the second rule matches against. ie. `/foo/bar/` is matched by both rules.

Whilst you say the first rule is "working fine", it looks like it might be matching too much due to the optional slashes mid-pattern. It will match URLs of the form `/foo/`, `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar/baz/` - is that the intention?

The quick fix is to simply reverse these two directives, so the more specific rule (that matches exactly 2 path segments) is first. The "more generic" rule (that matches one, two or three path segments) would then follow.

However, I would also check that the first/original rule is working as intended. eg. Should a request for `/foo/` be routed to `estates1.php?pageNum_Clusterb=&estname=foo&location=`?